# downgrading nbformat to prevent "Notebook JSON is invalid" errors

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I'm trying to run `nbconvert` on a large bunch of Jupyter notebooks. These are assignment submissions from my students. The problem is that I get the following message

```
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Notebook JSON is invalid: {'model_id': '5d85f9c5bb174b0f86e823471671928a', 'version_major': 2, 'version_minor': 0} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

When I run `conda list nbformat` I get

```
# packages in environment at /home/taylor/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0
```

I read somewhere that the error goes away if you open up the notebook in Jupyter notebook,and run every cell. However, I don't have time to do that. Should I just downgrade to version, say, `4.4.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading worked:

`conda install nbformat=4.4.0`

This is the version that all my students have.